# Recuperar chave e valor de campo específico no Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

Por favor, gostaria de recuperar apenas a chave e o email da lista, ignorando os demais "campos". Queria ter uma lista, sem carregar todos os valores de todos os nós, como tenho feito ultimamente.

Como conseguir isso com javascript ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe esta opção. O que você pode fazer é mapear somente estes campos com um Json só para este fim, e passar a gravar os registros tanto na estrutura completa quanto na que estou propondo. Desta forma terá duas estruturas disponíveis para leitura/gravação.

Comment: Ricardo, eu ja havia feito deste jeito. Fiz uma function que mantem esta lista de dados atualizada. obrigado.